# Calling a function when all asynchronous calls complete

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Below is a simplified version of some code I am using to execute a function after all asynchronous calls complete.  Is this a reasonable piece of code? It seems to work.  Nothing would break if `DoStuff()` was called twice, though that would be very inefficient.

```
var i = 0;
var done = function () {
    i++;
    if (i < 2) return;
    //Everything is done
    DoStuff();
};
elem1.executeAsync(function () {
    done();
});
elem2.executeAsync(function () {
    done();
});
```

Comment: So you want `DoStuff()` called only when *both* are done?

Comment: @SomeKittens: Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach itself (i.e. using a counter) is reasonable, but the hard-coded `2` and `DoStuff` limits its use.

You could do something like this, to derive more generic implementation:

```
function createCounter(count, callback) {
  count || (count = 1); // default to 1
  (typeof callback === 'function') || (callback = function () {}); // default to no-op
  return function () {
    --count || callback();
  };
}
```

Now you have a function that returns a specialized "done" function. Use like so:

```
var done = createCounter(2, DoStuff);

elem1.executeAsync(function () {
  done();
});

elem2.executeAsync(function () {
  done();
});
```

Incidentally, this can be shortened to:

```
var done = createCounter(2, DoStuff);

elem1.executeAsync(done);
elem2.executeAsync(done);
```

(of course, your actual code is likely more complex)

However, I'd say you should also look into the [Promise/Deferred patterns](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises).
For instance, using jQuery's implementation (and assuming `executeAsync` returns a promise) you can do this

```
$.when(elem1.executeAsync(), elem2.executeAsync()).then(DoStuff);
```

Comment: executeAsync is not under my control.

Comment: @Brian Ok, but apart from the last bit about promises, that doesn't affect my answer.